# How to create Request and Response classes for custom entity in MSCRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create request and response classes for custom entity. I did not find a way using crmmsvutil. It will generate proxy classes. But, How to create Request and Response classes for custom entity in MSCRM 2011?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, these requests are defined in the [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334698.aspx) and [Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309482.aspx) dlls.

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages - contains the more generic requests and repsonses, e.g. Create, Update, Delete

Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages - contains the crm specific requests and respones, these all achieve a specific function, e.g. Assing, AddToQueue, BookRequest

There aren’t any messages specific for custom entities or system entities, e.g. there isn't a CreateContactRequest, you would just use `serivce.Create(new Entity("Contact"));`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such requests. Take look at methods

```
Entity Retrieve(string entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet);
```

and

```
EntityCollection RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query);
```

You have everything to retrieve any kind of entity, so, no purpose to have special request classes.